# replacing the tag data with data saved from sql

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a mvc controller which have a static page with table html tags. Now I have datas saved under sql which I wanted to replace the data.

For  instance, I have a this kind of the view page [Example](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_layout_float) then with the help of cs file I can change the header or footer for instance based on the data from database

How can I be able to modify the tags? As I am new for this I need some guidance regarding this?

Just a request if you think this not a related post then instead degrading it please let me know I will delete it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying using ViewBag or ViewData from the controller to display values in the table, then use a conditional in C# Razor to check the data and modify your tags based on what comes from the ViewBag and ViewData.

More information here: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-framework-part-3-passing-viewdata-from-controllers-to-views

Another option is to use JavaScript to check for values from POST method.